# Datatables server side scripting became endless in my spring project

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, datatables

I added server side processing for my ajax. Without server side processing the data successfully retrieved. But i want to add it. I reduce my data in MySql as 25 rows.when execute it also became endless and show nothing.i went to developer options in chrome and check network.It retrieveed all style sheets without endless. Whats the error in my jsp. I use Spring mvc

This is my code. Please help me some one

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tableProduct = $('#example2').DataTable({"bInfo": false
                , "bLengthChange": false
                , "bSort": false
                , "oLanguage": {"sZeroRecords": "", "sEmptyTable": ""}
                , "processing": true
                , "bServerSide": true
                , "ajax": {
                    "type": 'GET',
                    "url": '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProduct',
                     "pageLength": 5,
                     "recordsTotal": 268,
                     "recordsFiltered": 268,
                     "draw": 52,
                    success: function (result) {
                        var jString = JSON.stringify(result);
                        var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);
                        for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                            var td1 = jdata[x].serialNo;
                            var td2 = jdata[x].slsiUnit;
                            var td3 = jdata[x].itemDesc;
                            var td4 = jdata[x].slsNo;
                            var td5 = jdata[x].hsCode;
                            var td6 = jdata[x].hsCode;
                            var td7 = jdata[x].hsCode;
                        }
                        tableProduct.row.add([td1, td2, td3, td4, td5, td6, td7]).draw(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this is my rest service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ViewProduct", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@JsonIgnore
public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> listAllProducts() {
    List<Product> viewProducts = productServices.getProductList();
    if (viewProducts.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(viewProducts, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Json response is

```
[{"productId":9,"serialNo":2,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Soya Bean Oil","slsNo":293,"hsCode":"1507.90","userId":null},
    {"productId":11,"serialNo":1,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Soya Bean Oil","slsNo":293,"hsCode":"1507.10","userId":null},
    {"productId":12,"serialNo":3,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Ground Nut Oil","slsNo":720,"hsCode":"1508.10","userId":null},
    {"productId":13,"serialNo":4,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Ground Nut Oil","slsNo":947,"hsCode":"1508.90","userId":null},{"productId":14,"serialNo":5,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Palm Oil","slsNo":720,"hsCode":"1511.10","userId":null},{"productId":15,"serialNo":6,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Palm Oil","slsNo":720,"hsCode":"1511.90.20","userId":null},{"productId":16,"serialNo":7,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Palm Oil","slsNo":720,"hsCode":"1511.90.90","userId":null},{"productId":17,"serialNo":8,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Palm Olein","slsNo":961,"hsCode":"1511.90.90","userId":null},{"productId":18,"serialNo":9,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Palm Stearin","slsNo":960,"hsCode":"1511.90.10","userId":null},
    {"productId":19,"serialNo":10,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Sunflower Seed oil","slsNo":946,"hsCode":"1512.11","userId":null},{"productId":20,"serialNo":11,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Sunflower Seed oil","slsNo":946,"hsCode":"151.19","userId":null},{"productId":21,"serialNo":12,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Coconut Oil","slsNo":32,"hsCode":"1513.11","userId":null},{"productId":22,"serialNo":13,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Coconut Oil","slsNo":32,"hsCode":"1513.19","userId":null},{"productId":23,"serialNo":14,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Palm Kernel Oil","slsNo":862,"hsCode":"1513.21","userId":null},
    {"productId":24,"serialNo":15,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Palm Kernel Oil","slsNo":862,"hsCode":"1513.29","userId":null},{"productId":25,"serialNo":16,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Maize(Corn oil)","slsNo":905,"hsCode":"1515.21","userId":null},{"productId":26,"serialNo":17,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Maize(Corn oil)","slsNo":905,"hsCode":"1515.29","userId":null},{"productId":27,"serialNo":18,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Sesame (Gingelly) Oil","slsNo":231,"hsCode":"1515.50","userId":null},{"productId":28,"serialNo":19,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Noodles","slsNo":420,"hsCode":"1902.11","userId":null},{"productId":29,"serialNo":20,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Instant Noodles","slsNo":420,"hsCode":"1902.19","userId":null},{"productId":30,"serialNo":21,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Macaroni","slsNo":420,"hsCode":"1902.20","userId":null},{"productId":31,"serialNo":22,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Spaghetti","slsNo":420,"hsCode":"1902.30","userId":null},{"productId":32,"serialNo":23,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Rice Noodles (Rice Vermicelli)","slsNo":858,"hsCode":"1902.11","userId":null},{"productId":33,"serialNo":24,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Rice Noodles (Rice Vermicelli)","slsNo":858,"hsCode":"1902.19","userId":null},{"productId":34,"serialNo":25,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Rice Noodles (Rice Vermicelli)","slsNo":858,"hsCode":"1902.20","userId":null},{"productId":35,"serialNo":26,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Rice Noodles (Rice Vermicelli)","slsNo":858,"hsCode":"1902.30","userId":null},{"productId":36,"serialNo":27,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Biscuits and Cookies","slsNo":251,"hsCode":"1905.31","userId":null},{"productId":37,"serialNo":28,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Jam","slsNo":265,"hsCode":"2007.10","userId":null},{"productId":38,"serialNo":29,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Jellies","slsNo":265,"hsCode":"2007.91","userId":null},{"productId":39,"serialNo":30,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Marmalades & Preserves","slsNo":265,"hsCode":"2007.99","userId":null}]
```

Comment: It is not required `success` function. When the server returns the data, the datatables will populate the table if the data matches table.  Please add the data structure that returns from your rest service to the answer .

Comment: @Gurkan Yesilyurt iadded the rest service

Comment: data retreive success from rest service.. I think the error is in my jsp

Comment: I need see JSON. Type `localhost:8080/yourapp/restservice/ViewProduct` to the browser.

Comment: [{"productId":9,"serialNo":2,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Soya Bean Oil","slsNo":293,"hsCode":"1507.90","userId":null},{"productId":11,"serialNo":1,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Soya Bean Oil","slsNo":293,"hsCode":"1507.10","userId":null}]

Comment: these are some feilds in json response

Comment: @Gurkan Yesilyur added json response

Comment: okey I will try on my local

Comment: thank u sir...if you can its more useful sir...thank you

Comment: Have a look at this -> **https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching** It is great you are tuning in to having your problem solved, but perhaps you could remove some of the 6 (six) almost identical questions you have posted the last 2 days about this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried as follows and work well.

We have several option:

**1) Array:**
[Ajax data source (arrays)](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html)

Remove `success` function and make use of `dataSrc` function.

In this case, the data we need:

```
"data": [
    ["",""],["",""]
]
```

**Code:**

```
"ajax": {
  "type": 'GET',
  "url": '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProduct',
  dataSrc : function(result) {
   var data = [];
   $.each(result, function (i,item) {
    var inData = [];
     inData.push(item.serialNo);
     inData.push(item.slsiUnit);
     inData.push(item.itemDesc);
     inData.push(item.slsNo);
     inData.push(item.hsCode);
     data.push(inData);
    });

    return data;
   }
}
```

**2 ) Object:**
[Ajax data source (objects)](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

In this case, the data we need

```
"data": [{"id": "1",},{...}]
```

**Code:**

```
var tableProduct = $('#example2').DataTable({
      "info": false,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "processing": true
      "serverSide": false
      "pageLength": 5,
      "ajax": {
        "type": 'GET',
        "url": '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProduct',
         dataSrc:""
    },
    "columns": [
       { "data": "productId" },
       { "data": "serialNo" },
       { "data": "slsiUnit" },
       { "data": "itemDesc" },
       { "data": "slsNo" }
   ]
});
```

### UPDATE

---

### Server Side Processing

We need the JSON structure contains recordsTotal,pageLength,recordsFiltered.

```
{
"data":[
 {"productId":1,"serialNo":1,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Data1","slsNo":0},
 {"productId":3,"serialNo":1,"slsiUnit":1,"itemDesc":"Data2","slsNo":0}
],
"recordsTotal":10,
"pageLength":3,
"recordsFiltered":10
}
```

Then we can use a wrapper class to obtain this: In this case, `Data` is your `Product` model.

```
class Wrapper{
    private List<Data> data;
    private int recordsTotal; 
    private int pageLength;
    private int recordsFiltered;
    public Wrapper(){}
    public Wrapper(List<Data> data, int recordsTotal, int pageLength, int recordsFiltered) {
        this.data = data;
        this.recordsTotal = recordsTotal;
        this.pageLength = pageLength;
        this.recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered;
    }
/*setter getter*/
}
```

To process paging we get some params in the controller and change the controller return the subarray according to `start` and `length` params:

`Datatable.js` sends `start` and `length` params to our service by each click to page number because of `serverSide=true`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ViewProduct", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Wrapper> listAllProducts(@RequestParam("start") int start, @RequestParam("length") int pageLength) {

    List<Data> returningData = getData(start, pageLength);
    Wrapper w = new Wrapper(returningData,10, 3,10);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(w, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I add some code for testing. You can change it to get the data from database.

```
public static  List<Data> viewProducts = new ArrayList<>();  
 static{
    Data d = new Data(1, 1, 1, "Data1", 0);
    Data d1 = new Data(2, 1, 1, "Data2", 0);
    ...

    viewProducts.add(d);
    viewProducts.add(d1);
    ...

 }
```

To get subarray of the array but there is logic bug needed refactoring.

```
private List<Data> getData(int start, int length){
  return viewProducts.subList(start, length+start);
}
```

And finally our script. This time we use `dataSrc:"data"` because of JSON returning.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var tableProduct = $('#example2').DataTable({
    "info": false,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "pageLength":3,
    "ajax": {
      "type": 'GET',
      "url": '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProduct',
      dataSrc:"data"
    },
    "columns": [
       { "data": "productId" },
       { "data": "serialNo" },
       { "data": "slsiUnit" },
       { "data": "itemDesc" },
       { "data": "slsNo" }
   ]
 });
});
```

---

You can find descriptions of other parameters such as `recordsTotal`, `recordsFiltered` at [Returned data parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir...I will ad this to my project.... if u haven't I cannot do that...what is the meaning of recordsTotal": 268, "recordsFiltered": 268, "draw": 52, these rows...I havnt any idea

Comment: I added the link my answer for parameters.

Comment: Sir is the serverside procession works in you cord... i think it doesn't work

Comment: It is perhaps a little bit overwhelming, the only thing OP need to do is to get rid of the success junk and use columns instead -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/1004/** but I am afraid it not is enough, since OP want serverside and by that also need to address all serverside issues in the rest service.

Comment: @ Gurkan Yesilyurt I use jquery-1.12.4.js and datatables 1.10.16 . But it does not working.. when i remove b in bServerSide word it gives all rows without pagination... I checked when chrome developer options it views serverside scripting success. but it doesnt't reduce mb usage. It refreash whole dataset... I want to add 10 rows for serverside processing at one time... From using it i can reduce page load time and mb usage...

Comment: @davidkonrad I want to add server side processing

Comment: @NipunVidarshana I update my answer and I test it, works well but you need to work on it a little bit.